# Laravel Vue SPA vs MPA/SSR

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Many laravel/vue tutorials use ajax calls to get the data. It seems that the SPA is completely isolated from Laravel. I.e. Laravel is just a data API and the vue app could also simply be hosted on a third party external server (e.g. AWS S3). Is this the recommended way, or should I rather use Laravel for Routing and have separate views that implement individual components and already included data instead of using a SPA?

Comment: I think what are you looking for is the difference between client-side rendering and server-side rendering. There are a plethora of information about that topic, like https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-tradeoffs-of-client-side-rendering-vs-server-side-rendering

Comment: It's not just about SSR. I am wondering about SPA vs MPA with vue

Comment: Have a look at https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "recommended way" because you're asking about two different but valid techniques.  Having different views and using laravel for routing would be the more "laravel" way to do it.  An SPA would lean more heavily into Vue and it's ecosystem.  Neither is more correct than the other at face value.

Answer (score 0):

For an SPA, I would recommend just going with the standard setup, which is Laravel on the webserver and Vue in the browser. To do this, install Laravel and Vue. AJAX communications from the browser to the server are accomplished with the Axios library which comes with Vue. Here is how to install Laravel and Vue router:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue

npm install && npm run dev

npm install vue-router

npm run watch
```

From within a Vue component, using Axios to communicate with the server looks like the following. Also, in the following, the endpoint is defined in the Laravel > Routes > web.php:

```
 methods: {

    fetchMessages() {

        let endpoint = `/channels/${this.activeChannel}/messages`;

        axios.get(endpoint).then(resp => {
                    this.messages = resp.data.messages;          
                });
    },
```

A Vue router is declared in the main js file. For instance, in app.js.

Here is what a Vue router looks like, and additional url paths would be added under "routes":

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
        base: '/',
        mode: 'history',
        history: true,

        routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: PostComponent
        },

    ],
});
```