# Deploy Vue SPA with Laravel Backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I am trying to figure out how I will deploy a Vue SPA with a Laravel backend on Ubuntu on DigitalOcean

I am currently able to deploy Laravel apps on Digital Ocean with no problem at all. My new challenge is that I am creating an SPA with the Vue-Webpack template and using a standalone Laravel app as backend.

I am not sure how I will deploy this and structure my folders on Ubuntu.

Comment: what are you using to serve the app? laravel,another php app, nodejs etc?

Comment: The backend is laravel, and the frontend is made with vue-cli

Comment: whats your index file of the app?

Comment: the index is coming from the Vue project. Laravel is only API.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: Laravel and Vue go hand in hand. There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540881/laravel-vue-spa-vs-mpa-ssr

Answer (score 8):

one way is to keep your projects in /var/www/ side by side in two folders(laravel-api and vue-app). another way is placing your app contents inside laravel-app's resources folder. configure nginx or apache to serve the laravel api backend only.

see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/backend.html

update **config/index.js**

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: true
  },
  dev: {
    port: 8080,
    proxyTable: {}
  }
}
```

from the docs

> **build.index**
>
> Must be an absolute path on your local file system.
>
> This is where the index.html (with injected asset URLs) will be
>   generated.
>
> If you are using this template with a backend-framework, you can edit
>   index.html accordingly and point this path to a view file rendered by
>   your backend app, e.g. app/views/layouts/application.html.erb for a
>   Rails app, or resources/views/index.blade.php for a Laravel app.
>
> **build.assetsRoot**
>
> Must be an absolute path on your local file system.
>
> This should point to the root directory that contains all the static
>   assets for your app. For example, public/ for both Rails/Laravel.

What you should do is serve your main index file through Laravel routes or some other method of serving. lets say you have home.blade.php as index file

1 - show application entry point

**routes.php / web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('home');
});
```

this index file should contain the app element. then you should use vue-router for navigation which will add # after index url.

**Here is how to configure javacript part**

2 - Install and Import VueRouter to /resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

3 - Use Vue router with Vue ( Vue.use(VueRouter);)

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);


window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

4 - Create /resources/assets/js/routes.js file

5 - Import vue router

6 - define routes

7 - Export routes

**routes.js**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home')
    },
    {
        path: '/another',
        component: require('./views/Another')
    }

];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
})
```

8 - Create /resources/assets/js/ app.js file which would be the javascript main app

9- require the bootstrap.js and Import routes.js file we created

10 - Use it set router: router (as we are using ES6 just router as defined below would be considered as router:router)

11 - Thats the new Vue app there

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import router from './routes';


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
    //app works go here
});
```

12 - Use app.js in the home.blade.php

13 - Add router links

14 - Add router view

**home.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <section class="section">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav class="tabs is-boxed">
                       <div class="container">
                           <ul>
                             <router-link tag="li" to="/" exact>
                                <a>Home</a>
                             </router-link>

                             <router-link tag="li" to="/another">
                                <a>Another</a>
                              </router-link>
                           </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                    <router-view></router-view>
                </div>
              </section>
           </div>

        <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

15 - Remember to run webpack.

Good luck

Comment: tnx @aimme for your response. I don't think i clearly stated what my challenge was. I can setup Laravel app and Vue with not problems. What i need help with is deploying both projects on Ubuntu droplet on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 5):

> I am assuming you have two folders for your project: `client` where your vue.js code goes in, and `server` where your backend code lives.

**The short answer**

Just copy the SPA build files (located in `client/dist` folder by default) into your `server/public` folder and deploy it (The same thing is true with express for Node.js).

**But you can do it better**

Surely you want to avoid the manual work of copying static files from `client/dist` to `server/public` on every build you do. This is easy, all you need is just changing the build folder in your `client/config/index.js` and make it your `server/public` instead of the default `client/dist`.

`client/config/index.js:`

```
build: {
  // change "../dist" to "../../server/public" in both rules
  index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
  assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
}
```

This is the recommended way to do it as described in the [webpack template guide](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/backend.html).

Comment: this is the description I was looking for. Thank you for this post!

Comment: ok so let's assume I have copied dist content into laravel's `project/public` and I have my server pointing to API app entry point, how do I make it display frontend, I can point my server either to api or spa

Comment: Abdelaziz Mokhnache , I have SPA which developed using Laravel 7 + Vue. It doesn't have a separate folder structure. All the Vue files are residing inside the resource/js folder. How could I deploy the my project into shared hosting? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361441/deploying-laravel-7-and-vue-js-full-stack-application-into-shared-hosting

Answer (score 0):

Check out my new project [Laravue-SPA](https://laravue-spa.wheelmaker.dev).  It's a framework that pulls together Laravel, Vue.js and Vuetify to create a single page application.

It's brand new and still pre alpha release but I'll be happy to provide support and fix bugs as they're discovered!

Plus it will introduce you to the concepts needed to create an SPA even if you go off in your own direction.