# Deploying Laravel 7 and Vue SPA application into shared hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router, shared-hosting

Experts,
My application has Vue front-end and Laravel 7 back-end. The issue was, I can't redirect to the login page and it shows me a blank screen. All the Vue files are residing in resource/js folder. There is no separate folder for front-end and back-end.

Network tab

[image]

console log

[image]
Folder structure:

- root directory has **quickpack** folder
- inside the **public_html** folder has the **public** files of my Laravel application

What I have done so far:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
      return base_path().'/../public_html/netlinkler/quickpack';
    });
}
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue')
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import ViewUI from 'view-design';
import 'view-design/dist/styles/iview.css'; 
Vue.use(ViewUI);
import common from './common';
Vue.mixin(common);

Vue.component('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').default)


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#hmp',
    router,
    store
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Delivery App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/all.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="hmp">
         @if(Auth::guard('employee')->check())
           <mainapp :user="{{Auth::guard('employee')->user()}}"></mainapp>
         @else
           <mainapp :user="false"></mainapp>
         @endif
       </div>
    </body>

<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"> </script>
</html>
```

EmployeeControler.php

```
public function index(Request $request){
        
               if(!Auth::guard('employee')->check() && $request->path() != 'login'){
                  return redirect('/login');
               }
        
               if(!Auth::guard('employee')->check() && $request->path() == 'login'){
                 return view('welcome');
               }
        
               return view('welcome');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'EmployeesController@index');
Auth::routes();
```

router.js

```
    const routes = [
    
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: home 
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: login 
        }
    ]

export default new Router({
    mode: "history",
    baseurl: "/api/v1",
    base: 'deliverywebapp',
    routes
})
```

Comment: Anything in `laravel.log`? Could you also post the XHR request for the login POST?

Comment: hi, lost.design.  There was nothing in XHR request.

Comment: What's in your console? There are 4 errors from what you can tell in the first screenshot.

Comment: lost.design  updated the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your application folder  to your route path

Or you can add a base path

export default new Router({

```
mode: "history",
baseurl: "/api/v1",
base: 'deliverywebapp',
```

const routes = [

```
{
    path: '/home',
    component: home 
},
{
    path: '/login',
    component: login 
}
```

]

})

or

export default new Router({

```
mode: "history",
baseurl: "/api/v1",
```

const routes = [

```
{
    path: '/deliverywebapp/home',
    component: home 
},
{
    path: '/deliverywebapp/login',
    component: login 
}
```

]

})

Comment: I have set in AppServiceProvider.php the public folder path. Wasn't that enough?